# How to list only files in a directory separated by commas

Tags: ls, text-formatting

So no directories and no hidden files. Just the files. Listing only files can be done with the line as follows.

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

Now I want the result of this line to be separated by commas.

Comment: Do you want the files separated by just a comma or a comma followed by a space?

Answer (score 29):

You can use `tr` for that job.

```
ls -p | grep -v / | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: With a ',' of course :)

Comment: True, updated the answer.

Comment: That works but I run into problems when I try to make an alias of it: alias lsf -m="ls -p | grep -v / | tr '\n' ' '" This doesn't work.

Comment: You can't alias to a command with arguments either alias to just lsf, or parse the arguments inside the alias

Comment: I was fiddling around with the `-m` (or `--format="commas"`) switch for `ls`, but this is the best solution. Upvote given!

Comment: I've never understood why aliases even *exist* - use a function: `lsf() { ls -p "$@" | grep -v / | tr '\n' ','; }`

Comment: By the way, this (like most filename parsing shell scripts I've ever seen) breaks if your filenames have newline characters in their names. Not that I've ever seen a file with a newline character in its name besides when I was pedantically testing if my scripts could handle filenames with newlines in them....

Comment: @reinierpost: If I remember right, aliases can do one obscure thing that functions can't, because of exactly when/how they're substituted during the shell's parse of the command line. But that's all I remember - since I read about the trick in question a couple years ago, I've never once felt the need to use it for something, so the details have faded from memory. So in almost every case, and definitely in this one, I agree - OP should use a function, not an alias.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the GNU `ls -m` command. It will print all files and dir separated by comma.

Comment: That works if you want a list of both files and directories, but not if want only the files.

Answer (score 7):

The solution proposed by Thomas works, but it adds a comma to the last item (which may not be what you want) and deletes the spaces after the commas. The following alternative preserves the spaces after the commas and does not add a comma after the last item:

```
 ls -1p | grep -v / | xargs echo | sed 's/ /, /g'
```

Of course, if you want to get rid of the spaces between the items, just tweak the sed expression:

```
 ls -1p | grep -v / | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

(Note to viewers who use a font in which a lowercase 'l' and the number '1' (one) look the same: the first option passed to `ls` is `1`, the number, not lowercase `l`.)

As Jim L pointed out in a comment, the above commands only work for file names that don't contain spaces. The following commands works around that:

```
 ls -1p | grep -v / | sed 's/$/, /g' | xargs echo | sed 's/,$//g'
```

This replaces the line endings with a comma before passing on the list to `echo`; the last part gets rid of the command at the end of the list.

Comment: This works only if the filenames do not contain spaces.

Comment: @JimL. Thanks for pointing that out. I have added another version of the command.